# How to trigger segfaults with apache2 & php5.6?

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

I really want to know a way how to trigger segfaulting with apache2 & php5.6 (and for example: wordpress), as i'm interested into tracking them down in a coredump.

Has somebody experience with this and / or a bulletproof method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: Just remove the "M" from the memory_limit variable. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault happens when the code attempts to access (for read or write) memory outside the area that was allocated to it; it is an error in the code of a compiled program. PHP scripts are interpreted; they don't access the memory directly, the interpreter handles the memory for them.

When the PHP interpreter or Apache produces a segmentation fault it's probably an error in the PHP interpreter or Apache code; **assuming they don't have errors**, there is no way to produce a segmentation fault using PHP.